# Sum:two different time query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, laravel

I set up my MySQL database with the field `'buy_datetime'` and `sell_datetime`. I want to get result of total time with different datetime in Hours. Format: `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'`.

For example,

1. buy_datetime - sell_datetime = 1result
2. buy_datetime - sell_datetime = 2result

OUTPUT
`Total in hours` = `1resul` + `2result`.

```
    public function firstHourHoldingTime(){

        $count_firsthour_holding_time =  DB::table('finaltrade')
            ->select(DB::raw('finaltrade.*'))
            ->sum(TIMEDIFF(Hour,"buy_datetime", "sell_datetime"))
            ->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need raw expression to sum up hourly difference between your columns

```
public function firstHourHoldingTime(){

    $count_firsthour_holding_time =  DB::table('finaltrade')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,buy_datetime, sell_datetime)) as total'))
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: I use this function occur error  -  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF' (SQL: select SUM(TIMEDIFF(Hour,buy_datetime, sell_datetime)) as total from `finaltrade`

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati use TIMESTAMPDIFF instead of TIMEDIFF